# How to avoid Google OAuth consent screen on Android

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, android-signing

I noticed that a lot of apps that I use (Pokemon GO, CityMapper, Booking.com and many others) Don't display consent screen when using google sign-in, however our app always displays it to all users.

[image]

The scopes we are requesting are: `email`, `profile`, `openid` according to consent screen settings (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)

But in code we only request `email` scope. I also noticed that I cannot remove them from Google developer console consent tab

[image: Google OAuth consent screen scopes]

How can I make sure that consent screen is not shown?

The code we use is as simple as that:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```

Just wanted to add that it's absolutely not clear from any of google docs on what makes consent screen show up or not

Comment: how are you making the API call that triggers the consent screen? can you add the code?

Comment: Redacting only some of the instances of the app name in the screenshot is not terribly effective ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm haha, just noticed it :) thanks

Comment: is there a reason for the duplicate `email` in the scopes?

Comment: @JakeP I wish I knew! I guess I can remove the duplicated one, the other one cannot be removed anyway

Comment: I only mention because Google could have it set up to ask for consent if you are requesting access to anything besides the default email profile and openid.  I don't know for sure but a possibility.

Comment: @Yuri Was there a screen preceding this one with a list of accounts to choose one, or how is the account specified? (do you collect email address in other UI and pass it into the API calls programmatically?)

Comment: @StevenSoneff yes there's a standard screen from google oauth api preceding this one where user selects his google account. A

Comment: It sounds like this is reproducible across a fresh account? From your description, there should not be any additional consent screen. Can you send the OAuth client ID and app info to sso@google.com so we can take a look?

Comment: Thanks @StevenSoneff, emailed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @steven-soneff above, the reason why my consent screen was shown is that I was requesting offline access from google oauth api